# Confusion on scope sharing in angular directive between link and controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am having a bit trouble understanding the following [code](https://github.com/johnpapa/angular-styleguide#style-y075)

HTML

```
 <div my-example max="77"></div>
```

Directive

```
        angular
            .module('app')
            .directive('myExample', myExample);

        function myExample() {
            var directive = {
                restrict: 'EA',
                templateUrl: 'app/feature/example.directive.html',
                scope: {
                    max: '='
                },
                link: linkFunc,
                controller: ExampleController,
                controllerAs: 'vm',
                bindToController: true // because the scope is isolated
            };

            return directive;

            function linkFunc(scope, el, attr, ctrl) {
                console.log('LINK: scope.min = %s *** should be undefined', scope.min);
                console.log('LINK: scope.max = %s *** should be undefined', scope.max);
                console.log('LINK: scope.vm.min = %s', scope.vm.min);
                console.log('LINK: scope.vm.max = %s', scope.vm.max);
            }
        }

        ExampleController.$inject = ['$scope'];

        function ExampleController($scope) {
            // Injecting $scope just for comparison
            var vm = this;

            vm.min = 3;

            console.log('CTRL: $scope.vm.min = %s', $scope.vm.min);
            console.log('CTRL: $scope.vm.max = %s', $scope.vm.max);
            console.log('CTRL: vm.min = %s', vm.min);
            console.log('CTRL: vm.max = %s', vm.max);
        }
```

HTML

```
        <!-- example.directive.html -->
        <div>hello world</div>
        <div>max={{vm.max}}<input ng-model="vm.max"/></div>
        <div>min={{vm.min}}<input ng-model="vm.min"/></div>
```

Why is `scope.vm.min` defined in `linkFunc`? Does the link function shares the scope of controller? Even so, why is `vm` automatically added to the scope without the explicit assignment  like `$scope.vm = vm` ?

Answer (score 0):

vm is stored in the $scope of the controller. 
Using this in directive, we use scope instead of $scope. Thus,in this case, as 'vm' is the $scope of the controller, it is same as the scope of the directive. And the link uses this by passing scope in the parameter for the linkFunc.
And also as directive uses the controller, same scope is carry forwarded to the link function.
Thus, we can directly use scope.vm.min and any other things.
I hope you understood.

Answer (score 0):

The `vm` is automatically added to the scope because of the `controllerAs` syntax in your directive configuration.

```
return {
    controller: Controller
    controllerAs: 'vm'
};
```

The `controllerAs` syntax creates an instance of your controllers function and everything on the `this` object will be exposed on the scope via the alias given in the `controllerAs` value. The `vm` exists in your `link` function because in your controller and in your link function you have the same `$scope` of your directive. It is not "shared" but it is the same. When the directive is compiled, it recieves a fresh new $scope to work with. On the compile time the controller comes along and attaches some info to the scope. And when the directive is fully rendered the `link` function powers up and the same `$scope` is provided in the function's parameter. That's why you have access tot the `vm` in the `link` function. And whatever you declare in your view, like the `ng-model=vm.min`, it will be also attached on the `vm` on the scope.

A more visual representation (aprox) of what is happening whe Angular compiles your directive:

```
// First step preparing the new scope and the directive configuration
var $newScope = $rootScope.$new(true); // true for isolated scope
var directiveConfig = {
   controller: Controller,
   controllerAs: 'vm',
   link: function(scope, elem) { ... }
}

// Attaching the new controller instante to your new scope
$newScope[directiveConfig.controllerAs] = new directiveConfig.controller();
// At this point, we have the scope.vm
//Compile the directive to recieve the rendered element attach to the DOM
var elem = $compile('<my-directive></my-directive')($newScope);
// At this point, our scope.vm now contains scope.vm min and scope.vm.max because of the ng-model
// Call the link function with the newScope and the newly renrered element
directiveConfig.link.call(null, $newScope, elem);
```

Answer (score 0):

strongly suggest you to learn the basics of directives [http://www.sitepoint.com/practical-guide-angularjs-directives/](http://directives)

also the vm is nothing but you must be using `controlleras` syntax so they mean

> this

as an instance of the controller